# Component Not Receiving newProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im currently creating a comment/message board style web app and having trouble rendering comments the way I'd like to. I want the comment list to update immediately upon post completion, but my component isn't receiving newProps. Am I mutating my state somewhere and simply not seeing it? Thanks!

My Container Component:

```
class Ritmo extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getComments()
  }
  renderComments = () => {
    return this.props.comments.comments.map(e => {
      return (
        <Comment
          key={e.id}
          username={e.username}
          comment={e.comment}
        />
      )
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={container}>
        <div className={projectContainer}>
          <Text>This is my project, RITMO</Text>
          <Image imageSource="../../assets/instructor-screen.png" />
        </div>
        <div className={formContainer}>
          <Form />
          {this.renderComments()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ comments }) => {
  return { comments }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getComments })(Ritmo)
```

My actions:

```
export const GET_COMMENTS = 'get_comments'
export const getComments = () => {
  const request = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/comments')

  return {
    type: GET_COMMENTS,
    payload: request
  }
}

export const POST_COMMENT = 'post_comment'
export const postComment = (values) => {
  const request = axios.post('http://localhost:5000/comments', values)

  return {
    type: POST_COMMENT,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

My reducers:

```
import { GET_COMMENTS, POST_COMMENT } from '../actions'

const initialState = {
  comments: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_COMMENTS:
    return {
      ...state,
      comments: action.payload
    }
    case POST_COMMENT:
    return {
      ...state
    }
    default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Your reducers don't really make sense... when you post a comment shouldn't the store be updated? Also, there shouldn't be a `GET_COMMENTS` action. You can just access the store via `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: Am I not currently updating the store when I post? What would that look like? Also, how would I mount the comments on the initial render if I don't have the get comments action? Genuine questions, I'm fairly new to Redux! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** 
Your actions `getComments` and `postComment` needs to be [**thunks**](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) because they're async.

Here's a video that helps explain the role that thunks serve: 
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-dispatching-actions-asynchronously-with-thunks

(You'll need to wire up thunks using Redux's `applyMiddleware` when you `createStore`.)

These thunks won't directly be interpreted by your reducer, instead...

**2.** 
You'll need to create regular actions to handle the stuff you want to do after you `getComments` and/or `postComment`.

You want the comments that you fetch to be stored in state, so you'll make a `SET_COMMENTS` action, and your reducer will handle it the way you've got `GET_COMMENTS` wired up.

Your `postComment` thunk won't need a regular action (with your current code) because you aren't changing the Redux state in response to anything after you post.

These steps together look like this:

```js
// Actions
const SET_COMMENTS = "set_comments";
const setComments = comments => ({
  type: SET_COMMENTS,
  payload: comments
});

// Thunks
const getCommentsAsync = () => dispatch => {
  return axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/comments")
    .then(comments => dispatch(setComments(comments)));
};

const postCommentAsync = comment => dispatch => {
  return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/comments", comment);
};

// Reducer
const initialState = {
  comments: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_COMMENTS:
      const comments = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        comments
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```